# RS485 Troubleshooting

Tags: arduino-esp32, rs485, nrf52840

[Schematic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLBQy.png)

I have one master(ESP32-S3) and one slave (nRF52840) device connecting via RS485 but it is not working. I am attaching the schematic picture for reference.

I have connected the direct UART TX and RX of master and slave to verify the device is working or not And it is working.

Comment: _"it's not working"_ is not a problem description. You don't seem to have determined whether the problem is even software-related. It's difficult to see how anyone could offer an answer to this.

Comment: Do you also connect the common ground between ESP32-S3 and nRF52840? Question about connectivity has nothing to do with software, and if you still have problem, try to post in https://electronics.stackexchange.com with detail explanation.